# Cypress - How to break out of .each loop with an if/else

Tags: loops, cypress, break

Is it possible to break out of nested .each loops from an if-else statement?

I'd like to:

1. Get the text from each element
2. Check if it is included in an existing string
3. As soon as a substring that isn't included in the original string is found, click on the element with said substring
4. Exit the loop

The return false doesn't trigger -- right now the test fails because after the item is clicked on, the loop is still running and cannot find the next elements of each, since it's now on a new page. Would it be possible to fix this, or would it be best to use a different approach?

```
 it("Test", () => {
    cy.get('[data-testid="item"]').each(($el, index) => {
        cy.wrap($el).children().eq(1).each(($el) => {
            itemText = $el.text()
            cy.log(itemText)
            itemList = "list text here"
                if (itemList.includes(itemText)) {
                    cy.log("Skip this item")
                }
                else {
                    cy.log("Proceed with this item")
                    cy.get('[data-testid="item"]').eq(index).click()
                    itemFound = true;
                    return false;
                }
            })
        if (itemFound) return false;
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with removal of `cy.wrap()`. This allows the code inside `.each()` to be synchronous, and you can `return false` to exit early.

Since the `.eq(1)` only returns one item, there is no need to `.each()` after it, there-by removing your second problem.

Since `.click()` is an action, it will have side-effects and possibly make the DOM re-render, so you must perform the `click()` outside of (after) the `each()`.

```js
const itemList = "list text here"
let foundIndex;

cy.get('[data-testid="item"]')
  .each(($el, index) => {
    const itemText = $el.children().eq(1).text()
    if (itemList.includes(itemText)) {
      cy.log("Skip this item")
    } else {
      cy.log("This item is the one, save the index")
      foundIndex = index
      return false               // now exit
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.get('[data-testid="item"]').eq(foundIndex).click()
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.each()` with `.filter()` to select just the item you want to click.

Internally `.filter()` is looping over the `item` elements, and only returning those that are matching the `return` criteria.

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="item"]')
  .filter((index,el) => {
    const itemText = Cypress.$(el).children().eq(1).text()
    return !itemList.includes(itemText)
  })
  .first()  // in case multiple meet the condition
  .click()
```

or use `.not()` which is the opposite of `.filter()`

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="item"]')
  .not((index,el) => {
    const itemText = Cypress.$(el).children().eq(1).text()
    return itemList.includes(itemText)
  })
  .first() 
  .click()
```